# Comparing/Contrasting Cosine and Fourier Transforms

Tags: fourier-analysis

What are the differences between a (discrete) cosine transform and a (discrete) Fourier transform? I know the former is used in JPEG encoding, while the latter plays a big part in signal and image processing. How related are they?

Comment: They are basically the same thing, and it is very easy to translate between the two using the identity cos x = (e^{ix} + e^{-ix})/2.

Comment: I think this question is kinda of vague, and the wikipedia article seems to already do a fair amount of comparison. Could explain what confuses about the wikipedia article, or what is lacking there you would like more description with?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Cosine transforms are nothing more than shortcuts for computing the Fourier transform of a sequence with special symmetry (e.g. if the sequence represents samples from an even function).

To give a concrete example in *Mathematica* (`$VersionNumber >= 6`), consider the sequence

```
smp = {1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 4., 3., 2.};
```

The sequence has redundancy (e.g. `smp[[2]] == smp[[8]]`, but note that in usual Fourier work, the indexing is taken to be from $0$ to $n-1$ instead of $1$ to $n$). A sequence like `smp` is termed an *even* sequence. The discrete Fourier transform of `smp` can be expected to have redundancy as well:

```
Fourier[smp] // Chop
{8.48528137423857, -2.414213562373095, 0, -0.4142135623730949, 0,
-0.4142135623730949, 0, -2.414213562373095}
```

and the discrete Fourier transform is itself even. One could hope to have a way to compute the discrete Fourier transform without redundancy, and this is where the type I discrete cosine transform (DCT-I) comes in:

```
FourierDCT[Take[smp, Length[smp]/2 + 1], 1] // Chop
{8.48528137423857, -2.414213562373095, 0., -0.4142135623730949, 0.}
```

The more usual type II discrete cosine transform (DCT-II) is the redundancy-free method for computing the Fourier transform of a so-called "quarter wave even" sequence (with an additional transformation to make the results entirely real for real inputs). A quarter wave even sequence looks like this:

```
smp = {1., 2., 3., 4., 4., 3., 2., 1.};
```

and the correspondence (e.g. `smp[[2]] == smp[[7]]`) is easily seen. DCT-II requires only half of the given sequence to do its job:

```
Exp[2 Pi I Range[0, 7]/16] Fourier[smp]/Sqrt[2] // Chop
{4.999999999999999, -1.5771610149494746, 0, -0.11208538229199128, 0, 
 0.11208538229199126, 0, 1.5771610149494748}

FourierDCT[Take[smp, Length[smp]/2], 2] // Chop
{5., -1.577161014949475, 0, -0.11208538229199139}
```

(We see in this example that the exploitation of symmetry in this case led to a slightly more accurate result.)

The other two types of discrete cosine transforms, as well as the four types of discrete sine transforms, are intended to be redundancy-free methods for computing discrete Fourier transforms. For DCT-I, one can deal with a sequence of length $\frac{N}{2}+1$ instead of a sequence of length $N$, while for DCT-II, only a length $\frac{N}{2}$ sequence is required. This represents a savings in computational time and effort. (I assume the case of even length here; a similar symmetry property can be established for the case of odd length.)

In any event, I wish to point out two good references on how FFT and the DCTs/DSTs are related: [Van Loan's *Computational Frameworks for the Fast Fourier Transform*](http://books.google.com/books?id=ozcvQUqr-GIC) and [Briggs/Henson's *The DFT: an owner's manual for the discrete Fourier transform*](http://books.google.com/books?id=coq49_LRURUC).